# Materials: How to get this transparent screen look?

Tags: materials, node-editor

Alright Im trying to get something along the lines of a mix shader with image texture combined with emissive but transparent - these screens:

[image]

I have no idea how to go about this in cycles. What would create this material?

EDIT: this is what I have but not as desired:

[image]

Comment: Just an image texture and emission mix shader - I do not know how to implement transparency into that and not achieving the right look. Im new to nodes

Comment: @cegaton ^ What would you suggest from here?

Comment: if you already have an emission shader and mix shader, just add a transparent shader and then slide the bar to taste.

Comment: @icYou520 see edit - the transparency won't work

Comment: Why do you have the animation-nodes tag?

Comment: Delete the Diffuse shader and one of your mix shaders, plug in the image directly into emission shader, connect the emission shader and the transparent shader into the mix shader, Adjust slider to taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect could be achieved with 4 nodes.

[image]
[image]

- Add a emission shader (that your image will plug into)
- Add a transparent shader
- Add a mix shader

Plug your two shaders into the mix shader and slide the FAC value to taste.

After rendering I would bring the image into a compositor and add some glow around the hologram image to make it a little more believable.

Pics taken from [Unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/)

Photo by Javier Ramos on Unsplash
Photo by Justin-Lim-500765-unsplash